# Mail server docker container for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: docker, mail-server

Does there exist a low maintenance mail server for Arm configured as a Docker container? I no doubt could set one up by hand but I really have better things to do with my time, and I'm lazy :-)

Comment: `low maintenance mail server` is an oxymoron. [REF](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server). Find an `smtp relay` you can use instead. Here's [one approach to that using Gmail](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiPyMailer).

Comment: I fear Seamus is kind of right about "low maintenance" and "mail server" deserving lots of coughing when used together in a sentence -- or more specifically, they can be quite low maintenance once installed and running, but getting them installed and running can be more work than one might reasonably assume...for starters they are often in two parts (MTA + MDA, unfortunately not mind altering chemicals).